# Bitmap not found in System.Drawing in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bitmap

Maybe just an oversight on my part, but I can't make sense of this:

- I have the reference to System.Drawing in my project tree within the references
- I have the correct using statement `using System.Drawing;`
- I can access other members of this namepace
- [According to the docs, bitmap should be within this namespace.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.8)

However, if I try use a bitmap, I get the following error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

VS19-IntelliSense suggests to install the package `System.Drawing.Common`, however if I do that, I get yet another error, stating:

> The type name 'Bitmap' could not be found in the namespace
>   'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly
>   'System.Drawing.

How can I resolve this issue to actually use the `Bitmap` class?

Comment: You need to add the reference from the menu : Project : Add Reference : Net : System.Drawing.  Then add to top of module "using System.Drawing"

Comment: @jdweng Problem is, this is a Unity script and the option to add a reference is not available. However, as stated, `System.Drawing` is already in my list of References.Also, the using statment is already in the code...

Comment: It looks like they made their own copy of System.Drawing and it only has three or four types in it.  Lame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the `System.Drawing.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` into your Unity project folder. I put mine under `Assets/Plugins/System.Drawing.dll`.

This version will contain the `Bitmap` class. You will still have an error in the editor, but everything will compile fine and you should be able to use Bitmap in Visual Studio.

---

A problem you may now encounter when using certain types from this dll (e.g. `Color`, `RectangleF`) is that Unity gets confused between the 4.0 and 2.0 versions of the dll files. The only solution I found to resolve this is to change `Api compatibility Level` from `.NET Standard 2.0` to `4.0` under `Edit` > `Project Settings...` > `Player`. .

If you choose not to do this, you will find that there is `System.Drawing` in the `C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.2.0f1/Editor/Data/NetStandard/ref/2.0.0/netstandard.dll`. Removing this dll will cause Unity to complain until you restore it.

There are solutions suggesting to modify `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.0f1\Editor\Data\NetStandard\compat\2.0.0\shims\netfx\System.Drawing.dll` or `C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.2.0f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5\System.Drawing.dll`, but I would advice against this as it would impact other projects using the same Unity version.